# Como puede pasar este Jquery a Js puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Llevo ratos intentando pasar este Jquery a Js pero no logro tener exito. 
Este es el codigo

```
<h:body onload="ocultarSegunRol()">          
    <h:form style=" display:  none" id="formRol">
    <h:commandButton  id="rol" value="#{usuarioController.ocultar()}"  />
    </h:form>
    <li id="li_supervisor"> 
    opcion supervisor
  </li>
    <li id="li_vendedor">
  opcion vendedor
</li>                   

   </h:body>
   <script>
    function ocultarSegunRol(){
            var valorRol=document.getElementById("formRol:rol").value;
         if(valorRol==="[1]"){
            $("#li_vendedor").css( "display", "none" );
        }
        if(valorRol==="[2]"){
            $("#li_supervisor").css( "display", "none" );

        }

    }

</script>
```

Por favor necesito pasar esto a Js puro porque me esta dando pobrema usar Jquery en jsf, estoy usando templates.

Answer (score 1):

Lo unico que veo de ahi en jquery solo son tus cambios en el CSS. Su equivalente en Javascript seria:

```
<script>
    function ocultarSegunRol(){
            var valorRol=document.getElementById("formRol:rol").value;
         if(valorRol==="[1]"){
            // aca esta el cambio
            document.getElementById("li_vendedor").style.display = "none";
        }
        if(valorRol==="[2]"){
            // aca esta el cambio
            document.getElementById("li_supervisor").style.display = "none";

        }

    }

</script>
```

Solo son esas dos lineas asi que creo que tengas problemas.

Comment: No me ha funcionado ninguna de las dos propuestas

Comment: Como te habrás dado cuenta ambas respuestas que te dimos hace el en cambio de las mismas líneas de código y son exactamente las mismas respuestas... El problema puede estar en otro lado en tu código... Seria bueno que nos des más información

Comment: Gracias, he resuelto el objetivo que tenía el problema planteado, pero no por js sino por medio de un método en java. Gracias por responder a ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Quedaría con js puro de esta manera, seleccionamos con `document.getElementById()` y ocultamos o mostramos de esta manera `.style.display =`, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
function ocultarSegunRol(){
            var valorRol=document.getElementById("formRol:rol").value;
         if(valorRol==="[1]"){
            $("#li_vendedor").css( "display", "none" );
        }
        if(valorRol==="[2]"){
            $("#li_supervisor").css( "display", "none" );

        }

    }
    
    
    function ocultarSegundoRo1(){
    var valorRol=document.getElementById("formRol:rol").value;
      if(valorRo1 === "[1]"){
        
        document.getElementById('li_vendedor').style.display = 'none';
      
      }else{
        
        document.getElementById('li_supervisor').style.display = 'block';
        
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<h:body onload="ocultarSegunRol()">          
    <h:form style=" display:  none" id="formRol">
    <h:commandButton  id="rol" value="#{usuarioController.ocultar()}"  />
    </h:form>
    <li id="li_supervisor"> 
    opcion supervisor
  </li>
    <li id="li_vendedor">
  opcion vendedor
</li>                   

   </h:body>
```